# golang - fomatting struct to json

Tags: json, go, marshalling

Does anyone know how to set the tag names for multilevel structs?
The top level tag-names of the struct works ok, but all sublevels tag names have the same name as in the struct. Trying to set all tag-name to lowercase.

The code can be run [here](https://play.golang.org/p/kmn0wmMGGF):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type Source struct {
    Pointer   string `json:pointer,omitempty"`
    Parameter string `json:parameter,omitempty"`
}

type Error struct {
    Status int     `json:"status,omitempty"`
    Source *Source `json:"source,omitempty"`
    Title  string  `json:"title,omitempty"`
    Detail string  `json:"detail,omitempty"`
}

type Errors struct {
    Errors *[]Error `json:"errors"`
}

func main() {
    errors := new(Errors)
    errors.Errors = new([]Error)
    error := new(Error)
    error.Source = new(Source)
    error.Source.Pointer = "pointer"
    error.Status = 401
    error.Title = "title"
    error.Detail = "detail"
    *errors.Errors = append(*(errors.Errors), *error)
    response, _ := json.Marshal(errors)
    log.Println("response", string(response))
}
```

Output:

```
{
   "errors": [
   {
      "status": 400,
      "source": {
        "Pointer": "pointer",
        "Parameter": ""
      },
      "title": "title",
      "detail": "detail"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You have a `"` missing in ``json:pointer,omitempty"``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed a few quotes:

```
Pointer   string `json:pointer,omitempty"`
Parameter string `json:parameter,omitempty"`
                  // ^^^ Here.
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/P3oHK29VKQ.